# Custom dojo validation styles

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using the validationtextbox and that seems to work fine - but I want to display a message below the field, a 2px red border on the textbox and rather than a square with exclamation a red disc with exclamation to the right --- how might I go about this?

I was thinking that this is a custom widget or a series of custom widgets because I need similar functionality/display for select fields and date ranges From [date] To [Date]

I have only been using dojo for about a week so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to restyle it. As sample, ${theme} = nihilo

```
<style>
.nihilo .dijitValidationIcon {
   background-image: url(...)
}
nihilo .dijitError {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 2px;
}
.nihilo .dijitErrorFocused {

}
</style>
```

To reposition the tooltip with invalidMessage, you need to do so in the constructor of your ValidationTextBox.

The property to set is `tooltipPosition`. If there's no room below, the next in position array will be tested for enough space, then next etc.

```
new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
  ...
  tooltipPosition: ['below', 'right', 'above', 'left']
})
```